# How to update NewsItem.LastModified in sitefinity?

Tags: c#, backend, sitefinity

Like the title, i do flow this code in document of sitefinity.
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-edit-content part modify an item by id of it version. 
It work good but i try to modify "LastModified" of the newsItem => it auto update about curent date.

```
private void ModifyItemByLiveIDNativeAPI(Guid liveId)
{
    NewsManager manager = NewsManager.GetManager();
    NewsItem live = manager.GetNewsItems().Where(newsItem => newsItem.Id == liveId).FirstOrDefault();

    if (live != null)
    {
        //Edit the item to get the master version.
        NewsItem master = manager.Lifecycle.Edit(live) as NewsItem;

        //Check out the master to get a temp version.
        NewsItem temp = manager.Lifecycle.CheckOut(master) as NewsItem;

        //Make the modifications to the temp version.
        temp.Title = "New Title";
        temp.LastModified = new DateTime(2011,1,1);

        //Checkin the temp and get the updated master version. 
        //After the check in the temp version is deleted.
        master = manager.Lifecycle.CheckIn(temp) as NewsItem;

        manager.SaveChanges();

        //Publish the news item.
        var bag = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        bag.Add("ContentType", typeof(NewsItem).FullName);
        WorkflowManager.MessageWorkflow(master.Id, typeof(NewsItem), null, "Publish", false, bag);
   }
}
```

The title => update. but temp.LastModified => auto update to curentdate.
I dont know why and i search google for change LastModified but don't have result. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't now why but every time i call savechange(). lastModify auto update i think it a feature of sitefinity. 
I find another way to control my problem. Thanks all!!

Answer (score 0):

The CheckIn method updates the LastModified property internally, so try setting the LastModified directly on the Master *after* CheckIn.

```
master = manager.Lifecycle.CheckIn(temp) as NewsItem;

master.LastModified = xxx;

manager.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi. I am update in file Global.asx.cs. And when newsitem.savechange() => EventHub.Subscribe<IDataEvent>(DataEventHandler); it go to DataEventHandler and i wrote my code in this. I apply your way but after manager.SaveChanges();
master.LastModified => comback to curent date.

Comment: Can you provide the full code in your question, including the global.asax one? Also, what Sitefinity version is this?

Comment: After check. It happen everytime i change some thing and call savechange() in anywhere.
I think savechange() auto update LastModified.

Comment: This begs the question - why do you want to change this property ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to "back date" news item while importing from other platforms you probably want to update the temp.PublicationDate not last modified.